# Run react application - "inventory-site" using latest packages

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help me run the react application -"inventory-site" using latest packages from the following repo:
https://github.com/joamit/inventory.git.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you are new here, I think you may not get any thing, that is becasue: this is NOT the place for get help on topics like this one, only specified questions get answered in some cases

Comment: See how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show what you have done, some codes. The issues you have, errors to make your question clearer.